# Which ios version to go for and why?

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

/# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

9.0 didn't work for me. I changed to 10.0 and it worked. What does this actually mean? So if it's set at 10.0, then it works for anything 10.0 or above?
What if I set it as the latest version of iOS 15.4.1? Will it work for anything lower?

Answer (score 2):

This tells what is the minimum iOS version your app supports.

If you make it 15.4.1, your app will be available to only those iOS devices which has at least iOS 15.4.1 installed. You will miss out on lots of users who might not have upgraded to the particular version (some might be having iOS 14.x.y etc).

If you specify iOS 10.0, your app will be available to almost every iOS device for installation.

*Why you can't lower it?*
Some functionality in the flutter framework (or any other framework in general) might not be available in lower versions which will result in failure while compiling the app. Hence minimum version is required.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Rahul’s answer: There is no practical way to test your app below 10.0, so you don’t want 9.x or even older. There are five year old devices that don’t run 13.0, but they can all be upgraded to 12.5. So if you want to support an iPhone 6 (which is still a useful device), you support arm64 and 12.5.

All newer phones run 15.1. So if you don’t want to support 5 year old devices, I’d avoid extra work to run on iOS 13 and require say 14.2 (my last app did that and had no workaround for older systems anymore).